# Gridsome cookie SameSite settings

Tags: cookies, samesite, gridsome, static-site-generation

I have a site developed in Gridsome that would be deployed in AWS S3 as static content, but images for this site are located at a different static site.
I am having plenty of "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute" errors in the console - for each image from an external source.

How I can set SameSite: None; Secure; in Gridsome to allow pulling those images without errors?